# libGdx: My actor's sprite is rendedred like a black box on stage

Tags: android, libgdx, actor, stage, spritebatch

I'm a rudiment in libGdx. 
I'm developing a turn-based strategy game in Android.

Yesterday, I created an Archer who can shoot to distant units. I succeeded in showing kinda archery motion when the gamer decided to do it by using Animaion, but It is too hard for me to draw an arrow describing a parabola.

After a long time of googling, I find concepts of Stage and Actor, and I apply it. I set a stage, designate an arrow an actor, do addActor whenever the gamer order an archer to shoot.

***But the arrow's Texture is rendered like a black box!***

Please check my code. Thank you in advance.
Don't bother about 한글.

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMap;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMapRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.renderers.OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;

public class Main extends ApplicationAdapter {

    protected SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    private ArrayList<UnitClass> totalUnits = new ArrayList<UnitClass>();


    TiledMap tiledMap;
    private TiledMapRenderer tiledMapRenderer;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private Rectangle viewport;
    static protected Stage stage;

    @Override
    public void create() {

        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(false);

        tiledMap = new TmxMapLoader().load("map_stage01.tmx");
        tiledMapRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(tiledMap);
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();

        totalUnits.add(new archer("atlas_archer.txt",2, 3,true));
        totalUnits.add(new swordman("atlas_swordman.txt", 5, 3, true));

        stage = new Stage();
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        Gdx.gl.glViewport((int) viewport.x, (int) viewport.y, (int) viewport.width, (int) viewport.height);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        camera.update();
        tiledMapRenderer.setView(camera);
        tiledMapRenderer.render();

        /////////SPRITE BATCH start/////////
        spriteBatch.begin();
              유닛표시(); // a local method for draw sprites
        spriteBatch.end();
        /////////SPRITE BATCH end/////////

        //STAGE//
        stage.act();
        stage.draw();

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        super.pause();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        stage.dispose();
        spriteBatch.dispose();
    }
}
```

Here is my Archer class:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Animation;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas;

public class Archer extends UnitClass {

    /* setting Animation */

    public String shoot() {

     /* examination about shooting conditions... */

Missile arrow = new Missile("arrow.png", -98f, this, attackedUnit);
Main.stage.addActor(arrow);

    }
}
```

Here is my Missile Class:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Batch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor;

public class Missile extends Actor {

    private EquationClass equation;
    private Sprite sprite;

    float time = -7f;
    int pointCount = 13;
    float timeSeperation = unitClass.RUNNING_FRAME_DURATION;
    float totalTime = pointCount*timeSeperation;
    float distanceX;
    float distanceY;

    public Missile(String texturePath, float gravity, UnitClass shooter, UnitClass attacked) {
        this.sprtie = new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(texturePath)));
        this.equation = new EquationClass(gravity);
        this.distanceX = attacked.x-shooter.x;
        this.distanceY = attacked.y-shooter.y;
        setBounds(shooter.x,shooter.y,
                sprite.getWidth(),sprite.getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    public void act(float delta) {
        super.act(delta);
        time += timeSeperation;
        equation.시작속력.set(distanceX/totalTime
                ,distanceY/totalTime + 0.5f*(-this.equation.gravity)*totalTime);

    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {

        float x = this.getX() + equation.getX(time);
        float y = this.getY() + equation.getY(time);

        if(time>= 0f && time<=totalTime) {
            Color color = getColor();
            batch.setColor(color.r, color.g, color.b, color.a * parentAlpha);
            batch.draw(sprite, x, y);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see exactly what's causing the problem, but I do not advise loading a new texture in your Missile constructor. Textures claim native memory and most be `dispose()`ed or they will cause a memory leak. And it will slow down the game to load textures in the middle of gameplay. It is better to load all your textures with AssetManager and pass a TextureRegion reference to your game objects.

Comment: @Tenfour04 , Thank you very much! On using AssetManager, problem solved.